# What's the technical term for a function which delivers only few unique values?

Tags: functions, terminology

How is the technical term for a function which has only few unique values ?
Say y(x) has a range of real numbers and g(x) has a range of {5,10,15}. 
The range of g(x) is really small. Does there exists a technical term for this property ??

Comment: "$g$ has finite range"? Or "the range of $g$ contains only a few values"?

Comment: And if both ranges are finite, but once has more values than the other ?

Comment: Are you talking about just doing the comparison? For that, the precise-to-the-point-of-being-pedantic phrasing would be "the cardinality of the range of $y$ is larger than the cardinality of the range of $g$".